# Setting up mod_perl on OSX Lion Apache server

Tags: perl, apache, cgi, mod-perl

I am new to both perl and apache servers. I'm trying to get a basic Hello World going for a CGI script. Here is the code for my hello world CGI file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<H1>Hello World</H1>\n";
```

When I execute the CGI script on the command line, ./hello.cgi, it works, but when I open hello.cgi in my browser, it just displays the text of the cgi file.

When I look at my error_log in /var/log/apache2/error_log I can see that mod_perl is running:

```
Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.12.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

but when I run the following perl program, it appears that I don't have the "MOD_PERL" env variable:

```
if (exists $ENV{"MOD_PERL"}) {
   print "YAY!\n";
 }
else{
    print"mod_perl is not working\n";
 }
```

By the way, my hello.cgi file and the perl script above are located in /Users/myusername/Sites/

Could someone help me configure mod_perl properly so that I can properly view hello.cgi in my browser? I've been reading the mod_perl documentation and searching forums for many, many hours with no avail. Thanks in advance

@SebastianStumpf I got your first example to work, but I still can't seem to get a mod_perl script going. I've been reading through the documentation, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks for your help, by the way. I'm very grateful

UPDATE: i believe I got it working! Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/ is the better place to ask...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the stock Apache/Perl of Mac OS X Lion **and don't need mod_perl** then you don't have to configure anything. Just create your file with the .cgi extension in `/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables` and adjust the permissions via `sudo chmod 755 file.cgi`. The script will be executed via CGI (not mod_perl). I tried this and it worked just fine:

```
$ sudo -s
# cat - > /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/test.cgi
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use Data::Dumper;
print header, start_html, h1('works'), end_html;
^D

# sudo chmod 755 /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/test.cgi
# exit
```

Testing it:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.cgi
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 11 Jun 2012 22:29:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>works</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

If you need mod_perl, then have a look at the documentation. The [configuration part of the introduction](http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/getwet.html#Configuring_and_Starting_the_mod_perl_Server) should be all you need to get mod_perl running.

**EDIT:**

I've added the following lines to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, restarted the web server and mod_perl works:

```
LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
Alias /perl /Library/WebServer/perl
<Location /perl>
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
    Options ExecCGI
    PerlSendHeader On
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

If the script is saved in `/Library/WebServer/perl/` you can see that all mod_perl headers are available now, but I'd rather setup a private installation of Apache/mod_perl. [MacPorts](https://macports.org/) makes this a lot easier...

Comment: The first example is just CGI, no mod_perl. If you need mod_perl try the second one. Did it work for you?

Comment: I do need mod_perl. I think it worked. It could still be a CGI running over mod_perl right? Or can it not be a CGI for it to be using mod_perl?